# Git is prompting me for gitolite password

Tags: git, putty

On a windows 7 machine with Putty, Git (with Linux options) I have confirmed that I can reach the Git machine by doing `ssh -T gitolite@[host]` but still i get prompted for the gitolite password when I do `git clone gitolite@[host]:[project]`.

Comment: see http://gitolite.com/gitolite/sts.html#stsapp1

Comment: thanks. I'm trying everything in that link, but still no luck.

Comment: your key is in the ssh authorized keys list on the server, right?

Comment: yes, but it's a key generated on a different machine, since the admins only want us to use 1 key

Comment: but you are that key on your windows machine, yes?

Comment: yes, and it's working because I can do 'ssh -T' to the git machine.

Answer (score 0):

Works now that I created a putty compatible key using puttygen.exe (by importing the existing key file). Also need to be running pagent.exe and load the key. And in git bash shell make sure GIT_SSH points to plink.exe.